# How to auto select a radio button in a carousel in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, radio-button, carousel

in my angular app I am using npm-hm-carousel. I need to auto select the field in the middle of the carousel like in the photo.
But also i need to bind one of the ids to the selected item, when i scroll the carousel.

[image]

```
          <ngx-hm-carousel [(ngModel)]="currentIndex" [show-num]="3" [infinite]="infinite" [drag-many]="true"
        [aniTime]="200" [data]="selectedServiceObj.packages" class="carousel c-accent">

        <section ngx-hm-carousel-container class="content">
          <article class="item cursor-pointer" ngx-hm-carousel-item
            *ngFor="let package of selectedServiceObj.packages; let i = index"
            [ngClass]="{'visible': currentIndex===i}">
            <div class="package">
              <div class="well">
                <div class="row header-part">
                  <div class="col-sm-2">

                  <input type="radio" name="package" [value]="package._id" [checked]="i===currentIndex" [(ngModel)]="inputSelectedPackageId" (change)="changed($event)">

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </article>
          <ng-template #infiniteContainer></ng-template>
        </section>

        <ng-template #carouselContent let-package let-i="index">
          <article class="item cursor-pointer" [ngClass]="{'visible': currentIndex===i}">
            </div>
          </article>
        </ng-template>

        <ng-template #carouselPrev>
          <div class="click-area">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template #carouselNext>
          <div class="click-area">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        </ng-template>

        <!-- <ng-template #carouselDot let-item>
          <div class="ball bg-accent" [class.visible]="item.index === item.currentIndex"></div>
        </ng-template> -->

      </ngx-hm-carousel>
```

but in this way the value is not setting to the [(ngModel)] directive. I think it is because the radio icon is not clicking. but when i use the below code fragment for select the radio button manually, the [value] binds to  [(ngModel)]

```
<input type="radio" name="package" [value]="package._id" [checked]="" [(ngModel)]="inputSelectedPackageId">
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

as i know we can't bind a value to a radio button. Since the clicked state won't change in a radio button. But it is good if you can use checkbox. you ll able to bind values to a checkbox and identify the state change